# Rails: Count specific records then do calculation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, math, records

I am attempting to do a rails record count then do a calculation from those records to give me a final number:

Example

```
100 Records = A
30 Records = B
Total Records = C

A+(-B)=C
```

I am not even going to show you what I tried...  in retrospect I am very new to rails and it made no logical sense!

**UPDATE:**
To further expand:

When implementing this I realized that there might be some slight difference from what it solves above.
I have a MVC called "POST"  It was some records within the table one specifically is called "VOTE" the vote integer will consist of 1 or (-1).  Each post will have a VOTE column that represent a value of 1 or (-1).  I am trying to create an analytic metric that consists of the following:

TOTAL = (Total posts with Value 1) + (Total posts with Value -1)
Example

1234 = 2000 + (-776)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'll expand my answer below, I just wanted to help you clarify. "MVC" is the name of the design pattern Rails uses. The M stands for model, which is your database records. So, POST is a Model, not a MVC =. Anyway, check my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general,
    C = A.count + B.count

If you want C to be the union of A and B, then do

```
C = A & B
C.count # Number of elements in C
```

For your specific case:

```
yes_votes = POST.where('VOTE = ?', 1)
no_votes = POST.where('VOTE = ?', -1)
total = yes_votes.count - no_votes.count
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  When implementing this I realized that there might be some slight difference from what it solves above.